# Парсинг посредством Curl

Tags: php, curl

Добрый день. Пытаюсь получить данные с сайта azlyrics.com
Код следующий:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://azlyrics.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Host: www.azlyrics.com',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
'Accept: 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch',
'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
'Cookie: __atuvc=1%7C20%2C0%7C21%2C2%7C22%2C11%7C23%2C17%7C24; 
__utma=190584827.275519439.1495187050.1497360209.1497447294.9; 
__utmz=190584827.1497447294.9.6.utmcsr=azlyrics.com|utmccn=
(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/'
));

curl_exec($ch); 
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Выдает ошибку "Empty reply from server". Другие же сайты парсятся нормально. Что не так с этим не могу понять. Возможно и в коде у меня какая-то мелкая ошибка, или на сайте защита от парсинга непростая стоит. 
Вообщем направьте пожалуйста на путь истинный. Интересно понять в чем же там проблема.

P.S.: смена хостинга решила данную проблему

Comment: `echo 'Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($ch);` Что выдаёт ? У меня код сработал и результат нормальный

Comment: Выдает ошибку "Empty reply from server". Может проблема из-за хостинга? Возможен такой вариант?

Comment: Какие заголовки возвращает ? добавьте в вопрос

Comment: Status Code:200 OK ?

Comment: Если я все правильно понял, то вообще пустую страницу возвращает при запросе заголовков.

Answer (score 1):

Я хочу предложить вам более простой способ без curl

```
$el = '\r\n';
$settings = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: ru".$el.
              "Cookie: key=val".
                      "key1=val1".$el.
              "Другие header`ы"
  )
);

$res = stream_context_create($settings);

$result = file_get_contents('http://azlyrics.com', false, $res);
```

Comment: А чем он именно проще?